# Magento emails are not sending, works only in one (store lang) scope

Tags: magento

Got strange problem, really. Option in System > System > Mail Sending Settings (Disable Email Communications) to No. I was not installing any plugins, no updates are done. I have Magento 1.8.

That is what i am getting in magento log.

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:412
Stack trace:
#0 httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#1 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('sales_email_ord...', 'general', Array, Array, Array, '2')
#2 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1329): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#3 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(130): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#4 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
#5 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
#6 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Well it works only wheen i am on English site. Wheen i swich to other lang it does not work anymore, nor contact form or any other form. I have only two languages in my shop.

Comment: I would also like to get an answer to this :)
It seems that the problem persists only in languages other than english.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the answer is rather simple in the end, atleast in my case.
What you need to do is go to:

- app/locale/your_locale/template/email
- app/locale/your_locale/template/email/sales

and save all files as UTF-8 withot BOM